# yii afterfind pass array to view

Tags: php, yii

Inside my Model i have this code, this is partial code

```
protected function afterFind ()
{
    $car= Car::model()->findAll("car_id = '{$this->model_id}'");
    foreach($car as $cars) {
        $val['car_name'][] = $cars->car_name;
        $val['car_value'][] = $cars->car_value;
    }
    $this->car_arr = $val;

    parent::afterFind();
}
```

How do i pass array to view? When i do something like this, there was an error output by YII saying
`htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: this error should be happening in the view. can you locate, and show us the line where this error is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii `afterfind()` method is overrided to **Postprocess** AR attributes.

[From the docs:](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail)

> This method is invoked after each record is instantiated by a find
>   method. The default implementation raises the onAfterFind event. You
>   may override this method to do postprocessing after each newly found
>   record is instantiated. Make sure you call the parent implementation
>   so that the event is raised properly.

So it usually works like:

```
protected function afterFind()
{

  $this->attribute_a = customize($this->attribute_a); //return customized attribute_a
  $this->attribute_b = customize($this->attribute_b); //return customized attribute_b
  ....
  parent::afterFind(); //To raise the event
}
```

I am not sure what are you trying to do? but may be you want to automate some task (populating some array) after each find !!

In that case you can define a public array in your model:

`$public car_arr = array();`

Then populate it in your `afterFind()` and it will be accessible in the View.